# Strange css position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in my project. What I want to get is, to get choosen's dropdown over collapsible divs but it goes under other content. Here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/CFbpt/5/

What am I missing? how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: You need to set your css to "relative" not "absolute"

Comment: Your bootstrap CSS file has a rule for `.collapse` that sets visible to hidden. This causes the overflow to not display. However setting it to visible solves that problem and creates another in that the accordion then breaks. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CFbpt/14/

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of everything:

```
.collapse.in { overflow: visible; }
.chzn-drop { display: none; }
.chzn-container-active .chzn-drop { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/7HLyZ/3/

Comment: See what happens? goes underneath the upper one

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Changed it to `.collapse.in` so it only does it when the group should be visible.

Comment: Try to click on first accordion item multiple times.. Again same issue

Comment: I mean close first accordion item then try to reopen

Comment: I'm not quite seeing this problem.

Comment: Open your link and press 3 times on http://screencast.com/t/VehJy8S39g59 You'll see

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17360/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-wex)